# Plot cropped unexpectedly when overlaying graphics

Tags: graphics

My goal is to overlay two graphics;gcdf and ghisto. But when I overlay graphics using Show[], my plot is cropped unexpectedly as fig2..How to modify code?

```
\[Lambda] = 5; n = 100;
gcdf = Plot[
   CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/(\[Lambda]/n)], x], {x, 0, 1}];
ghisto = Histogram[
   RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[\[Lambda]/n], n]/n, Automatic, 
   "CDF", ImageSize -> 200];

{ghisto, gcdf}
```

fig1) graphics to be overlayed

[image]

```
Show[ghisto, gcdf]
```

fig 2) plot is cropped unexpectedly

[image]

Comment: Please include definition for `xn`.

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> {0, 1}` or `PlotRange -> All` in your `Plot`. It is not automatically adapted when you combine two graphics with `Show`, hence the blue curve is shown exactly as in your first image (namely from ~0.93 to 1).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrong point in the question and I've just edited question. And Thank you for your answer.I'm not sure about the behind rules for automatically cropping graphs, but thanks for your answer. As you pointed out,  when I add PlotRange option,the plot show fully.gcdf = Plot[
   CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/(\[Lambda]/n)], x], {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gcdf =
 Plot[CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/(\[Lambda]/n)], x], {x, 0, 1},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

ghisto = 
 Histogram[RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[\[Lambda]/n], n]/n, Automatic, "CDF", 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

Show[ghisto, gcdf]
```

[image]